# CakePHP not redirecting, no errors displayed

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a page to redirect after deleting some data. It previously worked, and I have since added a lot so I have no idea what's causing the issue.

Here's the function, generated through Baking. The strange part is the function works and properly deletes the record, but it just stays on the blank page.

```
public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Visit->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Visit->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid visit'));
    }
    $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
    if ($this->Visit->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Visit deleted'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Visit was not deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

However, when I change it to just redirect upon the function call, it works. Something is up with the delete and I can't seem to figure out what's happening.

```
 public function delete($id = null) {
    $this->Visit->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Visit->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid visit'));
    }

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Visit deleted'));
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

}
```

What can I look for? I don't have anything in my Models regarding redirects

Comment: *"I have since added a lot so I have no idea what's causing the issue"* -- Perfect example of why unit tests and a test-oriented workflow are so popular these days. In regards to your question, can you clarify what version of Cake are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.8. I also have the exact same code in another controller for deleting data and it's working fine. Could database relations be causing this?

Comment: Have you taken a look in the cake error logs?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the best practice for redirecting is to do `return $this->redirect(...);`. Doing so makes it friendly for tests ([source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers)).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the controller:

```
// http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html

$this->redirect(array('controller' => '<YOUR CONTROLLER NAME>', 'action' => 'index'));
```

You can alsy try this if you want to redirect to the referer page

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

For future work: you say " just stays on the blank page". What is your debug level? If it's in dev-mode the redirects are not automated done, but there's a link `continue to redirect` (text might be similar, don't have in mind). And you can see if the target is reachable, e.g. does the controller actions exists.